# Is there a way to generate Java code from UML Activity diagrams in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, uml, activity-diagram

I have seen previous questions on how to generate UML diagrams from code. Is there a way to do it in reverse, like having an existing activity diagram to convert into Java code?

Answer (score 1):

This would be possible. ADs have quite a limited number of language constructs. `Decision` would translate to a simple `if` construct. `CallBehavior` would just be invocation of a class operation. And `Fork`/`Join` would need some support to be mapped to invocation of system threading operations.

But that's not all of it. I don't know of any system that's described in full with ADs. There are usually only a few ADs and many (/most) use cases are just described in text.

There's [executable UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_UML) which might be something you can look into. I haven't seen it in reality in any project. To me UML is for (abstract) modeling. You don't bother too much with implementation. Then you pass on to the coder/hacker troop. They live in a somewhat different world. And you won't make them happy when doing all the programming already in UML. And for sure you won't get them into programming in UML.

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible to generate working code from UML. You can only generate objects with empty methods.

Enterprise Architect can do that, for example. It can also reverse engineer existing classes. But both features are (in my opinion) much less useful as it sounds. At the end, you make the work of the programmer more complicated as before. These diagram can even not replace manually created documentation.

Comment: `It is impossible to generate working code from UML. You can only generate objects with empty methods.` this is false. `Enterprise Architect can do that`how it can do that if this is impossible ? `It can also reverse engineer existing classes. But both features are (in my opinion) much less useful as it sounds` I do not share your opinion at all (=> BoUML).

Comment: I wanted to say that Enterprise Architect can generate objects with empty methods. You say this is false, so can possibly help the topic owner by giving him an example or naming a product that can do what he wants. How useful this is, is surely a matter of personal taste and experience.

Comment: I react on the fact you say "it is impossible to generate working code from UML" because, again , you are wrong, whatever the way to do. I BoUML I do not offer a code generator from activities not because this is impossible but because I (still ?) manage them partially, but I have a state machine generator producing C++ code. There is nothing making the code generation impossible from an activity, in fact this is exactly the reverse because they allow to model in detail a behavior. Perhaps you confuse activity and interaction ?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61899843/generating-python-code-from-a-diagram-uml-visual-representation

Comment: This is an opinion based answer.  While I respect your opinion, it seems based on a single tool.  I therefore invite you to expand your exploration, since there are plenty of tools that can generate code and do the reverse.  This is called [roundtrip engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_engineering).  For example [Rational Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Rose_XDE) offers it for C++ since 1994 (I haven't used it for a long time, so I don't know if it's still state of the art).